# bcrypt generates incorrect hashes - is my user-input processing correct?

Tags: go, stdin, bcrypt

I've written a short program in Go to generate a bcrypt password hash from a password provided via stdin. Minimal example below:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Enter password:")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    inputPassword, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')

    inputPasswordBytes := []byte(inputPassword)
    hashBytes, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword(inputPasswordBytes, bcrypt.DefaultCost)

    hashStr := string(hashBytes)

    fmt.Println(hashStr)
}
```

In another program (a Go web-server) I accept the user's password from a HTTP `POST` request and test it against a hash generated with the code above and saved to a configuration file that's loaded at startup, like so:

```
func authenticateHashedPassword(inputPassword string) bool {

    configPasswordHashBytes := []byte(server.Config.Net.Auth.Password)
    inputPasswordBytes := []byte(inputPassword)
    err := bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword(configPasswordHashBytes, inputPasswordBytes)
    if err != nil {
        return false
    }
    return true

}
```

However this reports failure when I know `inputPassword` is correct. After some investigation I saw that my initial `func main` above was generating the wrong output when I used this website to test my values: https://www.dailycred.com/article/bcrypt-calculator - it says all of the output I generate doesn't match the desired passwords.

I'm assuming there's something wrong going on with the character encoding or other details when I do `[]byte(inputPassword)` - is it perhaps including the trailing line-ending?

Unfortunately I cannot step-through debug my program because Visual Studio Code's Go language tools and debugger does not support using standard-IO: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go/issues/219

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [bufio Reader.ReadString](https://godoc.org/bufio#Reader.ReadString) method returns the data up to and including the `\n` delimiter.  The `\n` is included in the password.  Use [strings.TrimSpace](https://godoc.org/strings#TrimSpace) to trim the `\n` and any whitespace that may have been entered by the user.

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "golang.org/x/crypto/bcrypt"
)

func main() {

    fmt.Println("Enter password:")
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    inputPassword, _ := strings.TrimSpace(reader.ReadString('\n'), "\n"))

    inputPasswordBytes := []byte(inputPassword)
    hashed, _ := bcrypt.GenerateFromPassword(inputPasswordBytes, bcrypt.DefaultCost)

    fmt.Printf("%s\n", hashed)
}
```

Comment: My program omitted a line where I did `hashStr = string(hashBytes)`. The output appearance (character range and text length of the bcrypt value) is the same in both cases.

Comment: When I run on Windows the `inputPassword` value contains a trailing `\r` - so I use `strings.TrimSpace()` instead of `TrimSuffix`.

Comment: Turns out I also had a secondary issue in my real code (not visible in the example I posted) where I shadowed the `inputPassword` value by mistake. I'm surprised Go doesn't warn me about that considering how strict the compiler is about everything else (e.g. unused variables).